# Ignore a module calling while executing script

Tags: python, maya

I apologise if my title is misleading as I am not sure how to write it. Anyway I am trying to load a file (let's called it - testNuke ) and running one of its function called `getNodes`
While I type the following in my Maya Script editor:

```
from nukeProcess.rendering import testNuke
testNuke.getNodes()
```

I got the error `ImportError: No module named nuke`. As I googled online, I found out that `import nuke` only works in the Nuke application script editor and having it to run externally would requires some other ways.

Hence I would like to know while I am executing the 2 lines code, can I perhaps add in another line to ignore the `import nuke`? Otherwise do I really have to kill that line off in the script, resave it then execute it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your example does not include any `import nuke`.

Comment: The `import nuke` is inside the `testNuke` file...

Answer (score 0):

you can use try and except method

```
try:
    from nukeProcess.rendering import testNuke
    testNuke.getNodes()
except:
    print 'Warning : nuke module can't be imported'
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A few assumptions need to be made regarding your modules

1. Any functions in which the `nuke` module is used are only called inside Nuke, and not part of what you're trying to call in Maya.
2. You have a good reason for needing to import a module which imports `nuke`, rather than Nuke- and Maya-based scripts which each import a generic rendering module. If not, consider restructuring it like that
3. You need to actually execute some part of the module, and cannot just skip it entirely

Assuming all that, you'll want to wrap the `import nuke` (which is in your `testNuke` module) in a try..except block:

```
try:
    import nuke
except ImportError:
    # handle it somehow
    pass
```

How you handle the `ImportError` is up to you. Obviously as I've written it, any attempts to call a Nuke function will raise a `NameError`.

If you want to make a special exception for those cases, you should write our own `nuke` class with a `.__getattr__` method, which in turn raises your custom exception. If that's a route you'd like help going down, it's probably beyond the scope of this question and could be asked as a new one, independent of your Maya specifics.